# Classify data with a perceptron in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I am generating random data that can be separated linearly. I want to write my own version of a perceptron to separate them. I know there are some post, that have similar problems - but I can't find my mistake. I am really stuck. The algorithm works, but doesn't seem to converge. I would appreciate if you could help me.

My code:

**single_layer_perceptron.m**

```
% INPUT
% amount of values
points = 20;
% stepsize
s = 1.0;

% INITIALIZE
% Booleans
TRUE  = 1;
FALSE = 0;

% generate data
D = generateRandomData(points);
% x-values
x = D(:,1);
% y-values
y = D(:,2);
% training set
d = D(:,3);
% weights
w = zeros(3,1);
% bias
b = 1;
% sucsess flag
isCorrect = FALSE;
% correctly predicted values counter
p = 0;
% COMPUTE 

% while at east one point is not correctly classified
while isCorrect == FALSE
    % for every point in the dataset
    for i=1 : points
        % calculate outcome with current weight
        c = heaviside(b * w(1) + x(i) * w(2) + y(i) * w(3));
        % compare output with training set
        a = errorFunction(c,d(i)); 
        % if outcome was wrong
        if a ~= 0
            % ajust weights
            w(1) = w(1) + a*s*b;
            w(2) = w(2) + a*s*x(i);
            w(3) = w(3) + a*s*y(i);
        else
            % increase correctness counter
            p = p + 1;
        end
    end

    %disp(w);
    disp(p);

    if p >= points
       isCorrect = TRUE;
    end

    p = 0;

end
```

**generateRandomData.m**

```
function f = generateRandomData(points)
% generates random data that can be lineary seperated (silent)
% generate random function y = mx + n
m = 2  * rand * sign(randn);   % in (-2,2)/0
n = 10  * rand + 5;            % in (5,15)

% generate random points
x = 20 * rand(points,2);        % in ((0,20), (0,20))

% labeling
f = [x, zeros(points,1)];
for i=1:length(x(:,1))
    y = m*x(i,1) + n;
    if x(i,2) > y
        f(i,3) = 1;
    end    
end

end
```

**activationFunctionHeaviside.m**

```
function f = activationFunctionHeaviside(x)
f = (1/2)*(sign(x)+1);
end
```

**errorFunction.m**

```
function f = errorFunction(c,d)
% w has been classified as c - w should be d

if c < d 
    % reaction too small 
    f = -1;
elseif c > d
    % reaction too large
    f = 1;
else
    % reaction correct
    f = 0;
end

end
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does exactly the variable "points" indicate? Ok, I saw in your comment line the number of values..that is? I am working, for example, onto the fisher iris data set; what can I "points" in this case replace with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [single-layer perceptron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron) is a linear binary classifier that **does not converge when the data is not linearly separable**. If we plot the data, we get both classes are overlapping.

[image]

We can solve this use, by adding a tolerance to your function **generateRandomData.m**

```
function f = generateRandomData(points)
% generates random data that can be lineary seperated (silent)
% generate random function y = mx + n
m = 2  * rand * sign(randn);   % in (-2,2)/0
n = 10  * rand + 5;            % in (5,15)

% generate random points
x = 20 * rand(points,2);        % in ((0,20), (0,20))

% tolerance
tol = 0.5;

% labeling
f = [x, -ones(points,1)];
for ii=1:size(f,1)
    y = m*f(ii,1) + n;
    if f(ii,2) > y+tol
        f(ii,3) = 1;
    elseif f(ii,2) < y-tol
        f(ii,3) = 0;
    else
        f(ii,1) = f(ii,1)+2*tol;
        f(ii,3) = 1;
    end    
end
end
```

However, your code still does not converge because your **errorFunction.m** has switched signs. It should be like this:

```
function f = errorFunction(c,d)
% w has been classified as c - w should be d

if c < d 
    % reaction too small 
    f = +1;
elseif c > d
    % reaction too large
    f = -1;
else
    % reaction correct
    f = 0;
end

end
```

Once, we do these changes, we get a nice linear classification:

[image]

Code to plot the hypothesis:

```
% Plot
idx = logical(D(:,3));
Xax = 0:20; Yax=-(b*w(1)+Xax*w(2))/w(3);
figure;
hold on;
scatter(D(idx,1),D(idx,2),'bo')
scatter(D(~idx,1),D(~idx,2),'rx')
plot(Xax,Yax,'k--')
```

Comment: It is good that it helped you. If this solution solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as the valid answer to help other users.

Comment: One more question: how did you graph the line? 
I tried:
`xValues = linspace(0,20,10);
 yValues = (-1 * ( xValues* w(1) + b * w(3) )) / w(2);
       `

Comment: @Chris, what does the tolerance do?

Comment: The tolerance is only used to generate the training data. It ensures that the labels are linearly separable in the feature space.

Comment: @tashuhka, This is a Binary Online Perceptron, Right?

Comment: It is a binary classifier because there are only two classes, which is always the case for a perceptron. The learning algorithm for the perceptron can be both online and offline. In this case, it is offline because the training samples are used several times until convergence.